# Is stack an efficient data structure?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, stack, stack-overflow

If two **stacks** growing in opposite directions are implemented within the same array, would this be a better solution or would this raise issues? Can somebody explain please.

Answer (score 0):

A priori, there is no issue. You can totally grow two stacks in opposite directions within an array.

In general, I don't think it's better or worse than growing the two stacks in two different arrays. Since most libraries provide an implementation for stacks, we usually don't bother implementing our own 2-stacks-in-one-array and we use simple stacks as they are implemented.

In some particular cases, using one array instead of two might be better, and in some other particular cases, it might be worse.

When allocating an array, we ask the operating system for a contiguous region of memory. If you want to allocate two size-10000 array, then you ask for a contiguous region of 10000 free spaces, plus another contiguous region of 10000 free spaces. If you want to allocate a size-20000 array, then you ask for a contiguous region of 20000 free spaces.

Obviously, it's easier to find two regions of 10000 spaces each, than one contiguous region of 20000 spaces. So in the case of two huge stacks, it might be better to use two arrays.

However, if you are working with two stacks with the property that the total number of elements is approximately constant, but the distribution of the elements among the two stacks is changing, then it might be more efficient to store the two stacks in the same array. For instance, if you start with 10000 elements in the first stack and 0 in second, then at some point there are 5000 elements in each stack, then later there are no elements in first stack and 10000 elements in second stack, then storing the two stacks in the same array might be much more efficient than using two separate arrays.

Comment: The flip side is that a "two stacks in one array" will fit as long as the arrays together have less than 20.000 elements. 5.000+15.000 will fit.

Comment: @MSalters Indeed! I added a paragraph to mention this.